# How To Solve This Jquery Page Refreash Error

Tags: jquery

I am creating a website where I have used a web service called holidaywebservice. I have used Jquery and Ajax to request and get a response from the server. When I input details, it shows the responses. But, the case is, when I input different details without reloading page, the response comes with an old response.

I used this `$('#tblData').load(row);`. But, nothing happens.

How can I show a new response without old response ??

Here is the code.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signupForm">

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                        Country : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" value="UnitedStates" id="country">
                        <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                        Year : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="year" value="2018"
                                      id="year"> <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                        Month : <input type="text" class="form-control" name="month" value="04"
                                       id="month"> <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                        Message Id : <input class="form-control" id="messageid" type="text"
                                            placeholder="Results will be placed here..." readonly size="40"/> <br>
                    </div>

                    <a href="#" id="ghsubmitbtn" class="btn btn-success">Search</a>

                    <p id="errorModal"></p> <br>

                    <div id="ghapidata" class="clearfix"></div>

                </form>
                </div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                <p id="body"></p> <br><br>
                </div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                Demo1 - <p id="demo1"></p>
                </div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                Country - <p id="Country"></p>
                </div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                HolidayCode - <p id="HolidayCode"></p>
                </div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->
                Descriptor - <p id="Descriptor"></p>
                </div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->            
                BankHoliday - <p id="BankHoliday"></p>
                </div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->        
                Date - <p id="Date"></p>    
                </div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->

                </div> <!-- End Of The Col Class -->

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 hero-feature"> <!-- Start Of The Col Class -->

                 <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-left" id="tblData">
                        <thead>
                        <tr class="info">
                            <td>Country</td>
                            <td>HolidayCode</td>
                            <td>Descriptor</td>
                            <td>BankHoliday</td>
                            <td>Date</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tbody id="tblBody"></tbody>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        $('#ghsubmitbtn').on('click', function (e) {
                            var country = $('#country').val();
                            var year = $('#year').val();
                            var month = $('#month').val();

                            //console.log(departureDate);

                            var str = '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>' +
                                '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">' +
                                '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                                '<ns1:GetHolidaysForMonth>' +
                                '<ns1:countryCode>' + country + '</ns1:countryCode>' +
                                '<ns1:year>' + year + ' </ns1:year>' +
                                '<ns1:month>' + month + '</ns1:month>' +
                                '</ns1:GetHolidaysForMonth>' +
                                '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                                '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

                            //console.log(departureDate);

                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?WSDL',
                                method: 'POST',
                                contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                                data: str,
                                dataType: "text",
                                //headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + bat},

                                success: function (data) {

                                    console.log(data);

                                    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=data;

                                    var xml = data,
                                      xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
                                      $xml = $( xmlDoc ),

                                      $CountryXML = $xml.find( "Country" )[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                      $( "#Country" ).append( $CountryXML );
                                      //document.getElementById("Country").innerHTML = $y.nodeValue; 

                                      //$HolidayCode = $xml.find( "HolidayCode" );
                                      //$( "#HolidayCode" ).append( $HolidayCode.text() );

                                      $HolidayCodeXML = $xml.find( "HolidayCode" )[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                      $( "#HolidayCode" ).append( $HolidayCodeXML );

                                      $DescriptorXML = $xml.find( "Descriptor" )[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                      $( "#Descriptor" ).append( $DescriptorXML );

                                      $BankHolidayXML = $xml.find( "BankHoliday" )[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                      $( "#BankHoliday" ).append( $BankHolidayXML );

                                      $DateXML = $xml.find( "Date" )[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                      $( "#Date" ).append( $DateXML );

                                      var BookBtn = '<input type="submit" value="Book" name="book" class="btn btn-primary">';

                                        for (var v = 0; v <= 999; v++) {
                                        var row = $('<tr><td>' + $xml.find( "Country" )[v].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</td><td>'
                                            + $xml.find( "HolidayCode" )[v].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</td><td>'
                                            + $xml.find( "Descriptor" )[v].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</td><td>'
                                            + $xml.find( "BankHoliday" )[v].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</td><td>'
                                            + $xml.find( "Date" )[v].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</td><td>'
                                            + BookBtn + '</td></tr>');
                                        $('#tblData').append(row);}

                                        $('#tblData').load(row);

                                }

                            }); //Ajax

                            //Test function
                            //createTableAndContent(soap)



                        }); //Button

                    });

                </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: put `ajax` call on `$(document).ready(function(){  });` insted of `button` click

Comment: @KiranJoshi - Then ajax will try to access web service when page loading. That's not what I want..

Comment: at which moment you get new data?

Comment: @KiranJoshi - After someone input data and click Search button.

Comment: than you need to call ajax on Search `button` click. get a response and then show it.you do not need `table.load` method

Comment: @KiranJoshi - Yes , I have put ajax inside the button. But, still when I try with new data it shows me response with old response. I want to know how to Fix this ??

Comment: Have you check ajax give you a fresh data?

Comment: @KiranJoshi - I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: your ajax response give you new data?

Comment: @KiranJoshi - At the beginning I insert new data to web service and click search button. Then I got response(A) accroding to the inputs. After I input different data and click search. At that time, it shows a new response(B) and old response(A) at once. How can show new responses each and every time without old response ??

Comment: I have answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your table first using `$('#tblData').empty()` method.
**or**  `$("#tblData").empty().append(data)`
So it clear your table and load a new one data in the table.

That's it!!

Comment: which method you have tryed?

Comment: For the first one - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).clear is not a function

Comment: Nop , it's not working.. When I use it, it disappear the table.

Comment: Where you put this method

Comment: After `$('#tblData').append(row);`.

Comment: You need to put it before `for loop..` because this method clear all content and than append new one

Comment: Yh , it's working now.. And Thank U !! But , now it shows data without that table. Can I get data inside the table ??

Comment: put your `tbody` outside of `thead`

Comment: the whole table disappear?

Comment: just use `$("table #tblData").append(data)` than your table look like as it is

Comment: Nop , I have done all the things as you said. but , still disappear the table. Table means, tables structure(<td>).